# How to send Oauth token from callback at the server to the client?

Tags: express, authentication, oauth-2.0, axios, passport-google-oauth

I am using expressJs and passport for authentication. I am using Google Oauth2.0 for login with standard Passport GoogleStrategy. At client I am using axios for sending a login request to the server. My login routes are :

```
router.get(
    "/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] }));

router.get(
    "/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/"}),
    function(req, res) {

        const token = jwt.sign({id: req.user.id}, configAuth.secretKey);
        console.log("generated token: ", token);
        res.json({success: true, token: 'bearer ' + token});

    }
);
```

I am using the user information from the callback to generate the JWT which I want to sent the client.

At the client I am using axios to send request and get the JWT and store it in localstore.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3001/google')
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("result", result);
    localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', result.data.token);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // if(error.response.status === 401) {
    //   this.setState({ message: 'Login failed. Username or password not match' });
    // }
    console.log("Login error", error);
  });
```

But Axios doesn't wait for the redirect to happen and returns a HTML document with Loading... message. If you try to access the API in the browser, it returns the desired JSON object. Is there a way to wait for redirects. Should I use another library to send login request?

I tried sending the token as url parameter with

> res.redirect()

but client and server are at different ports so it doesn't work.
Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Google's OAuth2 pathway redirects your browser, resulting in page reloads, a couple of times before it completes. As a result, your client-side code,

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3001/google')
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("result", result);
    localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', result.data.token);
  })...
```

will never reach the `.then()` block. You probably see this in the browser; you click a button or something to navigate to `'http://localhost:3001/google'`, and your `localhost:3001` server re-directs your browser to a Google login page. Now that your browser is at the login page, it has no memory of the `axios.get` statement above--that webpage code is gone.

You need to handle the JWT in client-side code that your server sends in response to

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3001/google/callback').
```

This is your browser's final stop in the OAuth2 path--once you get there, you won't be re-directed again. You can put your `axios.get` function above inside that client-side code.

Comment: Like this:

axios.get('http://localhost:3001/auth/google')
      .then((result1) => {
        console.log("result1", result1);
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/auth/google/callback')
        .then((result2) => {
          console.log("result2", result2);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Login error", error);
      });

It didn't work.

Comment: I left out the word "in" in one sentence of my answer, sorry; corrected

Comment: Google is redirecting the user's browser to `http://localhost:3001/auth/google/callback`. If you were to type `http://localhost:3001/auth/google/callback` into your browser, what do you want your browser to show?

Comment: That is just a rest API not a route. I do not want to show anything. I just want it to return JWT to the client.

Comment: The browser will be redirected to http://localhost:3001/auth/google/callback, whether you want to show anything there or not. It is there that JS code will need to handle the JWT. You need to write an HTML file that gets served to that address, and then also write a JS script to go with it that either gets the JWT from a cookie, or a header, or makes another API call, or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved the problem, there is a workaround use 'googleTokenStategy' instead of googleOAuth on passportjs. That way you can use react's GoogleLogin plugin to receive the access token from the front end and send it by axios.post to the backend link then set up the jwt. Reference [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W87udYTA1rw&t=1485s)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer